# lambda expressions c#

Tags: c#, lambda, function-composition

I would like to know how to make function composition using lambda expression.
I mean, I have 2 function f(x) and g(x). How to make their composition f(g(x)) using lambda expressions?
Thanks

Comment: You dont need expressions for this. Normal delegates suffice.

Comment: Note that "lambda expression" is just the code - it doesn't tell us whether that is becoming a delegate versus an expression tree. The two answers shown are for delegates; if it is actually an expression tree, please say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generic version:

```
static Func<T, T> Compose<T>(params Func<T, T>[] ff)
{
  Func<T, T> id = x => x;

  foreach (var f in ff)
  {
    var i = f;
    var idd = id;
    id = x => i(idd(x));
  }

  return id;
}
```

*Due to C#'s lack of proper lexical scoping, we need a whole bunch of temporary variables with different names.*

Comment: This gives `g(f(x))`, which may not be the same. To demonstrate try with f and g from my basic answer: `Console.WriteLine(Compose(f, g)(5));` prints 12 instead of 11.

Comment: @TrueWill: Just change `i(idd(x))` to `idd(i(x))` :)

Answer (score 2):

```
Func<int, int> f = x => x + 1;
Func<int, int> g = x => x * 2;
Func<int, int> fg = x => f(g(x));

Console.WriteLine(fg(5));
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question is very brief, I am not sure if I get it well, however I think this is what you need:

```
Func<int,int> compose(Func<int,int> f, Func<int,int> g)
{
    return x=>f(g(x));
}

var fg = compose(f,g);

Func<int,int> f = ....
Func<int,int> g = ....
Func<int,int> fg = compose(f,g);
```

The problem with C# is that you need to write such compose functions for each different method signatures and therefore you could not compose functions using a generic method.